# How to set up categories & sub-categories to fill dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, categories, megamenu

I set up a category database. After filling it it I wanted to fill a mega menu which i got from w3schools css mega menu.

**create_categories_table.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }
}
```

**Category.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}

?>
```

**CategoryController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
     public function index()
    {  
        $categories = Category::all();

        return View::make('index', compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

After setting up the category components i filled in the database with the information i needed [image: Sequel Pro Categories]

I then set up the navigation bar to attempt to fill the dropdown. As shown on the webpage like so [image: Website nav].

**navbar.blade.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    {{HTML::style('css/style.css')}}

</head>
<body>

    <div class="categories">
        <a href="#">Categories</a>

        <div class="kp-menu-container">

            <!-- // left menu.... -->
            <ul class="main">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <li><a href="">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <!-- // right menu....... -->
            <div class="kp-submenu-container">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <div class="submenu-content">
                        <h3>{{$category->name}}</h3>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($category->subcategories->take(20) as $subcategory)
                                <li><a href="">{{$subcategory->name}}</a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            <li><a href="">more subcategories..</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                @endforeach

                <!-- thanks for watching........... sssl    subscribe, share, like, comment................ -->

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {{ HTML::script('js/script.js') }}
</body>
</html>
```

I then placed the navbar code into my main home.blade.php my home page code like so;

**home.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    @include('master.navbar')

<div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <div class="card">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
        <div class="card">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:100px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Popular Post</h3>
            <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
            <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
            <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Follow Me</h3>
            <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</html>

@endsection
```

**web.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Route::get('/Home', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
//});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/email', function () {
   return new \App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail();
});

Route::post('follow/{user}', 'FollowsController@store');

Route::get('dashboard/profile', 'ProfilesController@show');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

Route::prefix('/recipes')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/create-step1', 'RecipesController@createStep1');
    Route::get('/create-step2', 'RecipesController@createStep2');
    Route::get('/create-step3', 'RecipesController@createStep3');
    Route::get('/create-step4', 'RecipesController@createStep4');
    Route::post('/create-step1', 'RecipesController@postCreateStep1');
    Route::post('/create-step2', 'RecipesController@postCreateStep2');
    Route::post('/create-step3', 'RecipesController@postCreateStep3');
    Route::post('/create-step4', 'RecipesController@postCreateStep4');
    Route::post('/remove-image', 'RecipesController@removeImage');
});


Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

I attempted a few variations of @foreach($categories as $category) around the dropdown section. however, I haven't been able to figure it out and my attempts have repeatedly gone wrong. I feel like my issue is that my CategoryController isn't being called when i use $categories as $category. and as such it reveals this error [image: Error]

Is this something i need to do in my web.php or within wither my navbar.blade.php/home.blade.php

Comment: can you provide categories model in your question ,

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh I think i've added what you've asked for

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh is it possible that you check over this, I have an idea of what the issue is, could you possibly help? (i have edited it into the above question)

Comment: @lAmTazlan
can you try like this
 " return View::make('index')->with('categories'); "

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh no that didn't work either. I think the issue is that my view or url in web.php for the /home page only calls the homecontroller@index is there a way to pass in categoriescontroller@index and subcategoriescontroller@index too?

Answer (score 0):

In category controller

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();
 return view('categories.index',compact('categories'));
```

In blade file

```
   <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <div class="header">
          <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
     </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <h3>{{$category->name}}</h3>
             @foreach($category->subcategories as $sub)
            <a href="#">{{$sub->name}}</a>
            <a href="#">{{$sub->name}}</a>
            <a href="#">{{$sub->name}}</a>
            @endforeach
         @endforeach
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry i've been ill for a while. However, I have made some adjustments since. Is this something you can help with still?